# Cant clear the value of TextInput in react-native

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyY5s.png)this problem show in ios,when i use TextInput of react-native,but it  can't type Chinese when using soft keyboard，so i modify the code like picture1,but  a new problem has arisen,when i enter the key to send ,the value of the TextInput cant clear.
what can i do?[enter image des`enter code here`cription here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChoYy.png)

```js
 <TextareaItem clear={true}  type="text" ref="text" value={this.state.meg}
 editable={true} disabled={false} onChange={(value) => {
                                    if (Platform.OS =='ios'){
                                        this.meg = value
                                    } else {
                                        this.setState({
                                            meg:value
                                        })}}} /> 

    sendMeg = () => {
        let message = ''
        if (this.meg !== '')
        messahe = this.meg
        }else{message = this.state.meg}
      this.meg = ''
      this.setState({  meg:''})
}
```

solve with this answer https://github.com/CHANOMA/react-native/pull/3/files#diff-8eb50d68d87e28556c034717cd58a86e

Comment: please post the code rather than adding images.

Comment: has been submitted code

Answer (score 0):

Set `this.state.text` to initially be an empty string `‘’`

Add an actual placeholder to your component and set the value to the string `‘Enter text…’`

Add the method `submitAndClear` to your class and set the component’s onPress prop to `this.submitAndClear`

Add the prop `clearButtonMode='always’` to the `<TextInput />` component — this will give you an option to clear the text at any time

The following can be used to clear the text

```
submitAndClear = () => {
  this.props.writeText(this.state.text)

  this.setState({
    text: ''
  })
}
```

You're good to go!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code where you want to reset  `meg` field:

```
this.setState({meg: ''})
```

Comment: i do it,but is useless

Comment: can you explain? what you get?

Comment: i had a problem just like this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19104,and then i fixed it to use the code just like

Comment: onChange={(value) => {
                                    if (Platform.OS =='ios'){
                                        this.meg = value
                                    } else {
                                        this.setState({
                                            meg:value
                                        })
                                    }

                                }}

Comment: ` <TextareaItem
  clear={true}
 type="text"
 ref="text"
 value={this.state.meg}
editable={true}
disabled={false}
onChange={(value) => {
 if (Platform.OS =='ios'){this.meg = value} else { this.setState({meg:value}) }}}
onFocus={() => { if (showEmoji) { openEmoji()}}}
rows={1}
autoHeight
clearButtonMode="always"
style={{maxHeight:106, backgroundColor: '#eae9ef',alignItems:'center'}}
                            /> 
`